# What would be the Slater's determinant representation for an excited state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

**Setup**

Introducing this spinorbital notation:

\begin{align}
\Psi_1=\chi_{(r1)}\alpha_{(\omega1)}  = 1 \\
\Psi_1=\chi_{(r1)}\beta_{(\omega1)}  = \bar{1}
\end{align}

and the Slater's determinant, for a system of two electrons, is:

\begin{align}
|\Psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \Big| 
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & \bar{1}  \\
2 & \bar{2}  \\
\end{array} 
\Big| = \frac{|1\bar{2}\rangle-|\bar{1}2\rangle}{\sqrt2}
\end{align}

**Question**

Based on the example, what would be the Slater's determinant representation for an excited state like $\Psi_a^r$ (*i.e.* with parallel spins like: $|\bar{1}\bar{2}\rangle$) and $\Psi_{ab}^{rs}$ (feel free to use any number) ?

Comment: The spin orbital definition confuses me, how can $\Psi_1$ be both spins? However, this is again a very interesting and challenging question and I would be happy to help out, I am however a little short on time right now. If I forget and you don't get answers, ping me here.

Comment: @Martin, thank you for your reply and about $\Psi_1$ imagine that it is a 1s orbital. In the case of two spinorbitals having the same spin is a case of excited state.

Comment: Of course - I thought so, but better be sure. I also get the general gist of the question, obviously, since I would like to help out. On the definition of excited states, this is of course only true, when the ground state is a singlet. There are cases, i.e. oxygen, where it is quite different. But that does not change the question at all, it just would make it much more challenging.

Comment: Feel free, thank you and have a good day :D (+1)

Comment: oki @Martin , what would you recommend me? just post one question in one site or post it in different sites to obtain more points of view?

Comment: The question you are asking is a good fit for either site, people who are likely to be able to answer this question are often active on both sites on the network. Ask it on one site, if you do not get answers, you can ask a moderator to migrate it to the other site. If you feel, it has not received enough attention, you can also add a bounty. There are very rare cases, where you might approach a problem from different angles, focussing on different aspects, then **always** include the link to the parent question. As far as I know that worked well with an cooking <-> chemistry exchange.

Comment: For the sake of transparency, I flagged this post to be migrated and merged with the one on physics. That might not happen, as this is a case for the moderators (I guess on either page) to decide.

Comment: @Martin ,so ... I won't receive help from both pages ever?

Comment: If you are cross posting, you might end up receiving no help from either page. If you would like to discuss that some more, I am available in chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slater [determinant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) is only a "trick" to get a total antisymmetric wave function. This is required by the [Pauli principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_exclusion_principle).

For understand this you need to think in indistinguishability of particles. So a any allowed state of a particle need to be assigned equally at each indistinguishable particle in your system. So if you have to state allowed: $|1\rangle$ and $|2\rangle$, then your state of the system is:

$$
|\psi\rangle=\frac{|1\rangle|2\rangle - |2\rangle|1\rangle}{\sqrt2}
$$

For a $N$ allowed states is something like:

$$
|\psi \rangle= \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} p(\sigma) \bigotimes_{i=1}^N |\sigma_i\rangle
$$

where $\sigma$ is a [permutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of $(1,2,...,N)$, $p(\sigma)$ is the [parity of the permutation $\sigma$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation), and $\sigma_i=\sigma(i)$ is the i-th number of the permutation $\sigma$. The big "O" with an "x" inside is:

$$
 \bigotimes_{i=1}^n |\sigma _i\rangle= |\sigma _1\rangle \otimes |\sigma _2\rangle \otimes ...\otimes |\sigma _n\rangle = |\sigma _1,\sigma _2,...,\sigma _n \rangle
$$
where $\otimes$ is a [tensor product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product).

Note that the tensor product is not commutative. Then, if you fixing some basis as the position ones, you get:

$$
\psi (x_1,x_2,...x_n)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} p(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^n \psi_i(x_{\sigma_i})
$$

The non-commutativity goes to $i$ labels, that maintains the order of the permutation $\sigma$. This is precise the formula of the determinant as you can see.

If you want to deal with extra state, you need to do the enumeration $(n,l,m_l,s)\rightarrow i$. e.g. the states allowed is $n=p_1,p_2$ and $s=\pm \frac{1}{2}$. We can enumerate: $(p_1,+\frac{1}{2})\rightarrow 1$,  $(p_2,+\frac{1}{2})\rightarrow 2$,  $(p_1,-\frac{1}{2})\rightarrow 3$ and  $(p_2,-\frac{1}{2})\rightarrow 4$. Some properties of determinant can help you to understanding the structure of this antisymmetric state.

Comment: Thank you @Nogueira, I appreciate your time for explaining me how to built an Slater determinant from the strictly math point of view. My tensorial background is not so good, as far as I know is a matrices product. In order to check your answer. would it be too much to just add an update following the given example? For me would be better, cos I just start to learn quantum mechanics from the very beginning and with no math strengths. Thank you again :D

Comment: Ok. The tensor product is not too important here. You can think as an operation that connect diferent quantum systems as only one. Then you may have states as $|\psi\rangle \otimes |\phi \rangle$, that is convenient writen as $|\psi \rangle |\phi \rangle$ or $|\psi, \phi \rangle$.

Comment: This mean that you have a state $|\psi \rangle$ for the first system and $|\phi \rangle$ for the second. However, you can make superpostion of states like $|\phi, \psi \rangle + |\psi ,\phi \rangle$, the entangled ones.

Comment: A system of indistinguishable particles need to be a state that is symmetrical (bósons) or anti-symmetrical(férmions) under a permutation of particles. This implies that you need to choose a entangled state one. Each tensor product of states need to be the same weight, with suitable signal such that the (anti-)symmetric requirement is accomplished.

Comment: For the case of Bósons, is easy, each tensor product has the same signal too. For Férmions, is more difficult, you need to choose the signals more careful. The Slate determinant is the key. Each permutation a column or a line change the signal of a determinant.

Comment: Your state have only the form $|1,2,...N \rangle \pm |2,1,...,N \rangle ...$ for each possible permutation. The slater determinant is only a expression for find the correct signals ones.